# Switching between two boolean values in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in a controller action, which looks at a user, and changes a boolean value to the opposite value, so if the user is `true` then it becomes `false`, and vice versa:

```
  if current_user.enable_access
    current_user.update_attribute(:enable_access, false) 
  else
    current_user.update_attribute(:enable_access, true) 
  end
```

Is there a neater way of writing this?

Answer (score 7):

How about using the [`toggle`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle-21) method that was specifically intended for this?

```
current_user.toggle(:enable_access)
```

If you want to add persistence in one character, there's also the [`toggle!`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle-21) method.

```
current_user.toggle!(:enable_access)
```

Comment: `toggle` won’t save a record, while `update_attribute` does. `toggle!` is just a syntactic sugar, but yes, it is :)

Answer (score 6):

In one line, if `current_user.enable_access` can be only `true``false`:

```
current_user.update_attribute(:enable_access, !current_user.enable_access)
```

Comment: Do you mean `current_user.update_attribute(:enable_access, !current_user.enable_access) ` (note the !)

Comment: thats so pretty i might just fall to my knees and weep with joy. Thanks :)

Comment: Gareth, try to restrain yourself. You'll wear out your pants if that's your reaction every time you discover something cool about Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

Here's something to meditate on:

```
false # => false
true # => true

!false # => true
!true # => false

foo = false # => false
!foo # => true
foo = !foo # => true

foo = nil # => nil
!foo # => true

foo = !nil # => true
foo = !false # => true
```

Notice `!!`, which is a convenient way to turn a value into a true/false:

```
foo = !!nil # => false
foo = !!false # => false

foo = 1 # => 1
!foo # => false
!!foo # => true

foo = 'a' # => "a"
!foo # => false
!!foo # => true

0 == 1 # => false
1 == 1 # => true

'a' == '' # => false
'a' == 'a' # => true
```

These are the building blocks for comparisons in Ruby.

Answer (score 3):

While the answer by @Зеленый is absolutely correct I wondered, that there is no DRY way to accomplish such a silly task.

The problem is that `true` and `false` in Ruby are instances of different classes, `TrueClass` and `FalseClass` respectively. That said, one can not just switch the boolean value inplace.

But what we can imagine, mediating at [`update_attribute` source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f50d953ff646b84a1c791a8034cfb4f3789fc8bf/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L250-L255)? Probably this is a shortest way to accomplish your task (please, do not use it at home, it’s a joke after all.)

```
current_user.tap do |cu|
  cu.enable_access ^= true
end.save validate: false
```

I just reinvented `toggle!`, thanks @Dremni for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

`current_user.toggle!(:enable_access)`

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-toggle-21

Answer (score 1):

I believe the DRY way to accomplish it would be to use:

`current_user.enable_access = !current_user.enable_access`

Then you could just write a method on a model and call it from any controller.

user.rb

```
def enable_user_access
    self.enable_access = !self.enable_access
end
```

then calling it from a controller

```
current_user.enable_user_access
```